# Failed to find worker. Code 404. When I invoke Stop Recording Restful API

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

When I invoke Stop Recording Restful API, `http://api.agora.io/v1/apps/<yourappid>/cloud_recording/resourceid/<resourceid>/sid/<sid>/mode/individual/stop` I am getting following error:

[image]

I am trying to record audio only and have enabled Amazon S3 with credentials.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured the storage with all your AWS credentials when sending the /api/start/ call?

```
                "storageConfig": {
                    "accessKey": "AKIA********",
                    "region": xy,
                    "bucket": "bucket-name",
                    "secretKey": "WpbL*****************",
                    "vendor": 1,
                    "fileNamePrefix": ["directory1","directory2"]
                    }
```

1. **accessKey , bucket and secretKey** You will find from your AWS console.
2. **region , vendor** (1 for S3 i'm sure) you can find the region(int) from this table here when the vendor is s3. You can check out the
   [documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=RESTful#parameters-1) if you're using some other storage option.

```
0: US_EAST_1
1: US_EAST_2
2: US_WEST_1
3: US_WEST_2
4: EU_WEST_1
5: EU_WEST_2
6: EU_WEST_3
7: EU_CENTRAL_1
8: AP_SOUTHEAST_1
9: AP_SOUTHEAST_2
10: AP_NORTHEAST_1
11: AP_NORTHEAST_2
12: SA_EAST_1
13: CA_CENTRAL_1
14: AP_SOUTH_1
15: CN_NORTH_1
16: CN_NORTHWEST_1
17: US_GOV_WEST_1
20：AP_NORTHEAST_3
21：EU_NORTH_1
22：ME_SOUTH_1
23：US_GOV_EAST_1
```

3. **fileNamePrefix** will basically just store your audio file in main_directory/directory1/directory2/file_name

If you've configured this in the previous start call before the stop call, then ideally there shouldn't be a *Failed to find worker* error :)

Comment: I was using GCP and still have the error . At the recording start every parameter for storing the recording in my GCP bucket is given . The strange part is this has stopped working since the last couple of months .

Comment: Our's was a stupid error . We used the wrong token and hence the recording never started and we were not realising this and called the stop call . Corrected it and its working . There is a 109 error code returns from Agoral Console .But we learnt about this error after reaching out to Agora support . Documentation : https://docs.agora.io/en/3.x/video-calling/reference/error-codes?platform=android